# BeautifulSoup script parsing Google search results stopped working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse Google search results with Python. Everything worked perfectly, but now I keep getting an empty list. Here is the code that used to work fine:

```
query = urllib.urlencode({'q': self.Tagsinput.GetValue()+footprint,'ie': 'utf-8', 'num':searchresults, 'start': '100'})
result = url + query1
myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.open(result)
xss = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(xss)
contents = [x['href'] for x in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'l'})]
```

This script worked perfectly in December, now it stopped working.

As far as I understand the problem is in this line:

```
contents = [x['href'] for x in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'l'})]
```

when I print contents the program returns an empty list: []

Please, anybody, help.

Comment: Are you trying to make automated requests to the normal google search web interface?  You shouldn't be at all surprised if they're blocking you; use their API.

Comment: this is not the case: the Soup results are present, I just can't parse the Soup.

Comment: Google regularly changes the layout of the front page in minor ways. If you're committed to the ill conceived idea of parsing the raw HTML you probably just need to figure out what the new attributes are after they redesigned it. Dump the soup and just look for the new way to identify it.

Answer (score 4):

[The API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/) works a whole lot better, too. Simple JSON which you can easily parse and manipulate.

```
import urllib, json
BASE_URL = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&'
url = BASE_URL + urllib.urlencode({'q' : SearchTerm.encode('utf-8')})
raw_res = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
results = json.loads(raw_res)
hit1 = results['responseData']['results'][0]
prettyresult = ' - '.join((urllib.unquote(hit1['url']), hit1['titleNoFormatting']))
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer you don't have to parse `<script>` tag (*for the most part*) to get the output from the Google Search. This can be achieved by using `beautifulsoup`, `requests`, and `lxml` libraries.

Code to get the title, link, and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Link-and-append-to-the-dictlist#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
    title = container.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = container.find('a')['href']
    print(f'{title}\n{link}')

# part of the output:
'''
Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
Minecraft Classic
https://classic.minecraft.net/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it as well by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # environment for API_KEY
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "minecraft",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  link = result['link']
  print(f'{title}\n{link}')

# part of the output:
'''
Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
Minecraft Classic
https://classic.minecraft.net/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.